# How would I apply classes to elements that are generated through a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have created some components through a loop

```
<li v-for="card in cardID" :key="card">
    <app-profile class="profile" :id="cardID[i++]"></app-profile>
</li>
```

I want to have a div around all of them so that i can centre the div, but I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a class to the generated list elements, you can use `:class="someClassName"` like this:

```
<li v-for="card in cardID" :key="card" :class="someClassName">
    <app-profile class="profile" :id="cardID[i++]"></app-profile>
</li>
```

---

And you don't need to wrap a div around the list elements to center them. Just add the center styles to the parent `<ul>` element instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `class` doesn't have to be a binding: you can do `class="classname"`. With `:class`, you'll need to pass in the name of an element in `data` that holds the string value of the desired class. Without the colon, you can pass the name of the class directly in the template.